# Immutable HashMap with mutable object as value

Tags: rust

I am looking for a way to update value of an immutable [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html).

I don't want to insert or delete a value from the [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) but just want to update the existing one.

So I am keeping the [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) object as immutable, but with that I can't update value stored in `map`.

Below is sample code:

```
fn main() {
    let map = std::collections::HashMap::from([(1,1)]);
    println!("{map:?}");
    match map.get_mut(&1) {
        None=>{},
        Some(val)=>*val=2,
    }
    println!("{map:?}");
}
```

I already know, making `map` to be `mut` this code works. But I want to understand

1. Why I can't change object contained in `map`?
2. Is there any implementation of a hashmap in Rust where I can change contained values on an immutable `map`?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e34d8ec0b6ed25cadaf3d335a5c17f63)

*Side Note*: **Why do I need this?**

*I want to protect map object with `RwLock` (or similar concepts), so some code can add/remove to map object and some code can just update existing object.*

Comment: Immutables cant be changed. Use clone: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-Clone-for-HashMap%3CK,+V,+S%3E

Comment: In opposition with C pointers, mutability/constness is **deep** in Rust data structures/containers. Mutating a piece of data owned by a container is considered as mutating the container. As shown in an answer, interior mutability is a way to circumvent this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [*interior mutability*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html):

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, collections::HashMap};
    
fn main() {
    let aa = HashMap::from([(1, RefCell::new(1))]);
    println!("{:?}",aa);
    if let Some(value) = aa.get(&1) {
        let mut value = value.borrow_mut();
        *value = 2;
    }
    println!("{:?}",aa);
}
```

result:

```
{1: RefCell { value: 1 }}
{1: RefCell { value: 2 }}
```

Comment: @cafce25 Agreed; edited.

Answer (score 3):

> Why I can't change object contained in map?

Because if you could call `get_mut` on an `&self`, you could write this:

```
let a = m.get_mut("foo")?;
let b = m.get_mut("foo")?;
do_something_with(a, b);
```

`a` and `b` are mutable references to the same object, which is illegal: you can not have aliasing mutable references. Hell, you could also write this, which is also illegal:

```
let a = m.get("foo")?;
let b = m.get_mut("foo")?;
do_something_with(a, b);
```

can't have both shared and mutable references to the same object at the same time.

Hence `HashMap::get_mut` takes a `&mut Self`, and you need mutable access to the map to get mutable access to any value.

> Is there any implementation of a hashmap in Rust where I can change contained values on an immutable map?

As trojanfoe responded, you can add a layer of interior mutability (RefCell, Mutex, RwLock).

You could also use a concurrent map e.g. [`DashMap`](https://docs.rs/dashmap/latest/dashmap/struct.DashMap.html#method.get_mut), *however* while `DashMap::get_mut` only needs a `&self` it may deadlock if there are outstanding references (it *will* deadlock if there is any outstanding reference to the shard the entry you're looking up).